# What are some of good books in probability?

Tags: probability, reference-request, soft-question

I am preparing for Ph.D entrances and my interest lies in probability and statistics. I am trying to learn it from William Feller's book but finding it quite difficult to comprehend. So please suggest me some good books on probability. Thanks!

Comment: Try Miller and Miller for stats and Hogg mckean for probability and mathematical statistics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good introductory probability book for graduate level?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494779/good-introductory-probability-book-for-graduate-level)

Comment: Look at the questions in the Related column.